# Encapsulating WCF Proxies in Static Classes

Tags: wcf, .net-3.5, proxy, encapsulation

I am designing a web service which will call different external web services according to the properties of a given object (a "request", for instance). A reference to these web services is added through the "Add Web Reference" menu in Visual Studio 2008, which, as you know, creates a proxy class for each endpoint which inherits from `System.ServiceModel.ChannelBase<ISomeInterface>` (where `ISomeInterface` is the endpoint defined by the specific service's WSDL).

The question is that I would like to encapsulate all those proxies in a single `ServiceManager` (for instance) static class containing, for example, an internal list of all the proxies, so that, on the one hand, all calls to a given service may go through `ServiceManager` instead of being scattered around the main application, and, on the other hand, new services which may be added latter can be made known to `ServiceManager` by a simple addition of a reference to the new proxy class.

I thought about desinging `ServiceManager` like

```
public static class ServiceManager
{
    #region Properties

    public static Dictionary<string, TProxy> ServiceList { get; private set; }

    #endregion
}
```

but I don't know what I should replace `TProxy` by so that all of the different proxies can be called by using `ServiceManager.ServiceList["ServiceName"]`. Can anyone please help me out with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since each service implements a different interface, it would have to be object... Unless you can create a common base interface, make the proxies inherit from that interface, and then create a List<MyBaseInterface>.

Why can't you just have one property on your class per proxy? At least then you could access the proxies in a strongly-typed way.

Comment: `ClientBase` implements `ICommunicationObject`, which is a good base interface for proxies. But proxies are not singletons, they are transitional objects.

Comment: Indeed. You may want ServiceManager to be a singleton. And understand that once a proxy is in Faulted state, it has to be re-instantiated.

Comment: pretty much. They also implement `IDisposable` although you should never actually use a `using` statement around them. Imagine that... a dispsable singleton.

Answer (score 2):

Do not reuse proxies. Re-instantiate them. Magic strings to differentiate between proxies are equally bad.

You are better off using static *factories* that return your service proxies than you are keeping only one instance of them.

Something like this:

```
public static class ServiceFactory
{
    public static Proxy CreateProxy();
    public static Proxy2 CreateProxy2();
    // etc.
}
```